# PHP not entering any data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Their are no errors but when i check phpmyadmin, it shows no data entry. Here is my code-

```
        <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="registered.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Registration details</title>
<?PHP
require ('C:/xampp/htdocs/try/connect.php');
$name = isset($_POST['usernamesignup']);
$email = isset($_POST['emailsignup']);

$password = isset($_POST['passwordsignup']);
$confirm_password= isset($_POST['passwordsignup_confirm']);
$password_hash = md5($password);



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$sql12="SELECT * FROM register";
$result12= mysql_query($sql12);
if($result12== FALSE){
die(mysql_error());
}
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result12)){
if($email==$rows['email'] ){
die('Sorry, The email-id you entered is present in our database. Please use your other ID. <a href="index.html"> Go Back </a>');
}
}


$query = "INSERT INTO register (name,password,email) VALUES ('$name','$password_hash','$email')";
mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('Error in connecting database');
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
</head>
Thank you for registering.
</html>
```

The code for connect.php is -

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','','register') or die('error connecting');
mysql_select_db('register',$link) or die('cannot select db'); 

?>
```

The output is thank you for registering. var_dump shows that the values are being posted. Please help.

Comment: Don't mix calls to `mysql_*()` and `mysqli_*()` - they are not the same and they're incompatible. Drop `mysql_*()` - it's deprecated.

Comment: I removed the require statement and instead added $dbc= mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','register') or die('Error in connecting to mysql');  @Hobo Sapiens. Still no error or data entry.

Comment: please use this debugging method rather than solution

`echo $query;`


copy your query and paste it in phpmyadmin SQL and see the error and correct this. . . .

Comment: Which debuging method @Anil Baweja ?

Comment: See the above comment. .

Comment: No help sir. Tried the method you told

Comment: use mysql_query rather than mysqli_query()    and mysql_close

Comment: @AnilBaweja No, __don't__ use `mysql_query()` - it's deprecated and will be removed from PHP in a future release. Use _only_ `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` (but don't mix them).

Answer (score 0):

### Don't mix mysql and mysqli

You're running `mysqli_query` on a `mysql_` connection. If you switch the connection to `mysqli_connect`, that will fix the particular issue you're having (read the docs to make sure this doesn't require any change to your arguments).

You have another `mysql_query` here:

```
$result12= mysql_query($sql12);
```

### Incorrect variable assignments

You're also assigning:

```
$name = isset($_POST['usernamesignup']);
$email = isset($_POST['emailsignup']);
```

Which, if set, will set both of these variables to `true`. This could be causing your MySQL query to fail when you try to pass them into the query.

You probably wanted to do this:

```
if (true === isset($_POST['usernamesignup']) && true === isset($_POST['email']) {
    $name = $_POST['usernamesignup'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
    throw new Exception('Username or e-mail address not sent.');
}
```

### Asidenotes

Xdebug is your friend, and so is `display_errors`.

While you're waiting for Xdebug to compile, I'd suggest looking up bound parameters (otherwise someone can do whatever they want to your database with this code as-is), and also why using `md5` to hash passwords is a really bad idea in 2015 (it's not much better than plaintext, look at `password_hash` and `password_verify`).